# Clean Conditional Code

Tags: php, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

i have this variable.

```
$productId = 2; // Testing ID
$value->id; // Contains INT
$value->datePurchaseEnd; // Contains UNIXTIME or NULL
```

The conditional i want to make.
`if ($value->id == $productId) return true;`

but if `$value->datePurchaseEnd;` is not `NULL` then also compare it with current time and it must bigger than current time to return `TRUE`;

For now this is the code i made:

```
if( $value->id == $productId){
        if( $value->datePurchaseEnd == NULL ){
            $return = TRUE; break;
        }else{
            if( $value->datePurchaseEnd > mktime() ){
                $return = TRUE; break;
            }
        }
    }
```

But i feel this code is not good.
Is there any suggestion to make better code with conditional above?

Comment: I strongly recommend not converting this into inline conditional for the sake of readability.

Comment: What should happen if the first condition is true, the second is false, and the third is false?

Comment: @xbonez if the inline you mean is like `$return = $foo == NULL ? TRUE : FALSE;` yes i will not make it like that too.

Comment: @JonathanM Then `$return` will `TRUE`

Comment: @GusDeCooL, that's not currently in your code. The way it is now, processing will fall through all the if's and else's and continue after the section you have posted.

Comment: @JonathanM on my actual script it already defined default as `FALSE`, but for this example, i forgot to meantion it. Apologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say either

```
if( ($value->id == $productId) && ($value->datePurchaseEnd == NULL || $value->datePurchaseEnd > mktime() )) {
        $return = true;
        break;
}
```

or

```
if($value->id == $productId) {
    if($value->datePurchaseEnd == NULL || $value->datePurchaseEnd > mktime()) {
        $return = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Depends on if the conditions need an `else`

Comment: it is mandatory to have `()` for first condition in `($value->id == $productId)`?

Comment: Not technically but I use it for consistency

Answer (score 2):

```
if( $value->id == $productId){
    $return = ($value->datePurchaseEnd == NULL || $value->datePurchaseEnd > mktime());
    break;
}
```

or

```
 $return = $value->id == $productId && ($value->datePurchaseEnd == NULL || $value->datePurchaseEnd > mktime());
 break;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is not in a loop, I do prefer the inline conditional:

```
return $value->id == $productId && ($value->datePurchaseEnd == null || $value->datePurchaseEnd > mktime())
```